# PHP PDO connect

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

Hello i am trying to do login with PDO but i faced with some problems. I always get Kazkas blogai message. Actually, i don't know where is my code problems. Here is example of PHP code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $user = "asgasgasg";
    $pass = "jhgjkghjghj";

    /* Pirmas etapas */
    if(isset($_POST['accept'])){

    try {

    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=abba_sql', $user, $pass);
    $connect->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $iname=htmlspecialchars($name);
    $ipass=htmlspecialchars($pass);

    /* Antras etapas */ 
    $sql = $connect->prepare("select * from FOO WHERE name = :name AND pass = :pass");
    $sql->execute(array(':name' => $iname, ':pass' => $ipass));
    $rows = $sql->fetchAll();
    $rowcount = count($rows);

    if($rowcount > 0){
        $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
        echo 'Viskas ciki';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Kazkas blogai';
    }

    $connect = null;
  }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}



    else {


?>
```

I would be glad if you help to me. I am trying to understand PDO basics. Thanks for your advices and help.

Comment: Why are you putting strings encoded with `htmlspecialchars` in your database? That function is for *outputting* data to web pages.

Comment: have you checked that the query works? What shows with `var_dump($connect->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($sql->ErrorInfo())`? Have you made sure that `$iname` has an account on the system, and the `$ipass` is the right password?

Comment: Check the return value of methods you call. PDOStatement::execute()` returns a boolean telling you whether the query succeeded.

Comment: $ipas has to be password type in mysql ?

Comment: Column of pass in mysql must have password encode?

Comment: Yes, passwords in your database should absolutely be salted and hashed! How are you storing them now? Also, read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for details about what @Marcel is talking about.

Comment: Now it's working, but if my encode type of pass was text; if it's password not working :(

Comment: What did you change? And I don't understand your sentence "but if my encode type of pass was text; if it's password not working".

Comment: It's working only if my column of pass has text encode. Otherwise, i face with same problem. But as i understand my column of pass must to have password encode. ? |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I want to aplogize for not giving any explanation for this code and I want to thank the one who editied my answer so the code got inside "code-blocks". I answered the question in a bit of a hurry through a smartphone. I wasn't able to add any code-blocks or formatting whatsoever with the phone.

Change

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$iname=htmlspecialchars($name);
$ipass=htmlspecialchars($pass);
```

To

```
$iname=$_POST['name'];
$ipass=$_POST['pass'];
```

*But here comes some explanination:* (If you haven't already figured it out)

If you have a username with some character that isn't letters or numeric and you have a username `hedge&hog`, then your example would assign the value $iname to `hedge&amp;hog`. (because `&` is converted to `&amp;`)

Because you're doing this conversion, your select-statment would look something like (**that is executed**):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='hedge&amp;hog' AND password='sdf893'; //Example password
```

When your **desired query** is:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='hedge&hog' AND password='sdf893'; //Example password
```

Above queries will for obvious reasons give different numbers of rows from your database...

The function **htmlspeciarchars()** is used mainly for **outputting** HTML so it uses html entities (when needed). It's not used for escaping characters, which I guess your intention was.

When using prepared statements you don't have to escape strings before inserting them into strings. This is because the actual values arent included in the actual query. They are just placeholders. Then the PDO (or mysqli) takes care of the escaping through it's functions like execute(), fetch() etc.

Making the values placeholders makes it much more safe then not using prepared statements:

**Example:**
***With prepared statements:***

```
SELECT * from username WHERE username=:username
```

***Without prepared statements:***

```
SELECT * from username WHERE username='hedge&hog'
```

If you take the first query above and execute it in your mysql-client it will return an error and the db-engine does not what to do with it. It's totally useless without som help-function for the db-engine. Therefore it's impossible to manipulate without using any code.

If you look at the second query, it's possible to execute and manipulate the username with the db-engine alone.

Therefore it's much safe with prepared statements.

I hope this helps you further!

Comment: Yes, but... some explanation would be nice.

Comment: Hmm... But is it safety ? ;/

Comment: @JuliusJ Yes, just read deceze's article. You escape/encode on *output*, not on input. Now the username `O'Connor` will be `O&#39;Connor`, who is probably not in your database.

Comment: Hmm... Nice.. It's my first time when i heard this, actually :)